# Appending to log file

Tags: c#

I am trying to to write data to a log file but nothing gets written to the file. 
Aim of the program is to run a continuous loop and keep looking for file, if file is valid, process it and move it. I am logging for any errors and items that are created. 
Also, how can I make my log file access able while the loop is running so that I can see that values got appended.

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var logFile = File.Create(filePath + "\\log_" + DateTime.Today.ToString("MMMM") + ".txt").ToString();

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                var moveTo = Directory.CreateDirectory(@"" + directoryPath + "Processed_" + DateTime.Today.ToString("MMMM"));
                var files = Directory.GetFiles(filePath);

                var todaysDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
                var firstOfMonth = new DateTime(todaysDate.Year, todaysDate.Month, 1);
                var monthEnd = firstOfMonth.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);

                if (todaysDate == monthEnd)
                {
                    File.Move(logFile, @"" + moveToNewPath + logFile);
                }

                foreach (var fileName in files)
                {
                    if (fileName.Contains("myFile.csv"))
                    {
                        var fileValues = File.ReadAllLines(filePath + fileName.Substring(44)).Skip(1).Select(v => new myFile(v)).ToList();

                        foreach (var i in fileValues)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                var jsonValues = ValueFromFile(i);
                                var response = UploadData(url, username, password, values);
 this should be written to a log file ===> .File.AppendAllText(logFile, Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now + "\t" + response); 
                            }
                            catch (Exception exception)
                            {
                                File.AppendAllText(logFile, Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now + "\t" + exception.Message.Replace("\n", " "));
                            }
                        }

                        File.Move(fileName, @"" + directoryPath + "\\" + moveTo + "\\" + "processedMyFile" + DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("MM-dd-yy") + ".csv");
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                File.AppendAllText(logFile, Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now + "\t" + exception.Message.Replace("\n", " "));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what problem are you having with your solution?

Comment: @Servy Nothing is appending to the log file. No data gets written.

Comment: Any comments on why the question should be closed?

Comment: You need to describe *in the question*, what the problem is, and you need to ensure that the code sample you've provided properly reproduces that problem in as small of a code sample as is possible.

Comment: Sure would be swell if you'd debug this yourself, step over the code, see where there might be exceptions you're not expecting getting thrown, etc..

Comment: @Servy, the description says the same thing, and the code reproduces the error when you execute it, i am not sure how to execute code on here.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, have been doing that, that is the reason I came here cuz on debugging, i can see the values but nothing gets written.

Comment: @Servy, if you are saying the code is too long, I am not sure how to reproduce the same error with a smaller code.

Comment: Nothing about that in the question, hence the close votes. We're not mind readers here.

Comment: @Servy, first line says "I am trying to to write data to a log file but nothing gets written to the file"

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan the first line states the problem, "I am trying to to write data to a log file but nothing gets written to the file".  Not sure what changes to make so that its more clear.

Comment: I copied your code to a new project and it doesn't compile. Close vote from me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with this line at the top of the program:

```
var logFile = File.Create(filePath + "\\log_" + DateTime.Today.ToString("MMMM") + ".txt").ToString();
```

I'm not sure what you're doing with that `ToString()` call hanging off the end. It almost certainly doesn't do what you think it does. But I really want to take a closer look at the [documentation for the File.Create()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03(v=vs.110).aspx) method here. Specifically, this excerpt:

> The FileStream object created by this method has a default FileShare value of None; no other process or code can access the created file until the original file handle is closed.

Uh oh. That means the `File.AppendAllText()` call later on will be out of luck. But let's look at the [AppendAllText() documentation.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356(v=vs.110).aspx) Specifically this:

> The method creates the file if it doesn’t exist

Meaning you can just remove the problem line at the top. You neither need nor want it. Or maybe you just want to create the file name there, like this:

```
var logFile = Path.Combine(filePath, "log_" + DateTime.Today.ToString("MMMM") + ".txt");
```

As a bonus, I'd explore changing this code to use `System.Diagnostics.Trace` in conjunction with `FileTraceListener` and maybe a `ConsoleTraceListener` attached.

```
static string moveToNewPath = "...";
static string filePath = "...";
static string logFormat = "\n{0:s}\t{1}";
static string logFile = "";
static string directoryPath = "...";

static void LogMessage(string FilePath, string Message)
{
    File.AppendAllText(Path.Combine(filePath, logFile),
         string.Format(logFormat, DateTime.Now, Message.Replace("\n", " ")));
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    logFile = "log_" + DateTime.Today.ToString("MMMM") + ".txt";

    //Rotate log file on last day of month
    try 
    {
        var todaysDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
        var firstOfMonth = new DateTime(todaysDate.Year, todaysDate.Month, 1);
        var monthEnd = firstOfMonth.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
        if (todaysDate == monthEnd)
        {
            File.Move(Path.Combe(filePath, logFile), Path.Combine(moveToNewPath, logFile));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         LogMessage(ex.Message);
    }

    while (true)
    {
        // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        //Log rotate code used to be here... but... you need something to be sure this only happens once per day.
        // I STRONGLY suspect this code should be setup to run as 
        //   a SCHEDULED TASK set to run once per day or maybe once per hour, rather than an always-on background program.
        // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        try
        {
            var moveTo = Path.Combine(directoryPath, "Processed_" + DateTime.Today.ToString("MMMM"));
            Directory.CreateDirectory(moveTo);

            var files = Directory.GetFiles(filePath).Where(f => f.EndsWith("myFile.csv"));
            foreach (var fileName in files)
            {
                var fileValues = File.ReadAllLines(filePath + fileName.Substring(44)).Skip(1).Select(v => new myFile(v));

                foreach (var i in fileValues)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var jsonValues = ValueFromFile(i);
                        var response = UploadData(url, username, password, jsonValues);
                        LogMessage(response); 
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        LogMessage(ex.Message); 
                    }
                }

                File.Move(fileName, Path.Combine(moveTo, "processedMyFile" + DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("MM-dd-yy") + ".csv"));
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogMessage(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I highly appreciate your in depth answer. Thank you very much.